# Hide Element in Fusion Tables Info Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-fusion-tables, infowindow

So, I've got a Fusion Table with a bunch of contacts, but some don't have emails or websites. I've mapped these to addresses, but I'd like to select an element within the info window (an `<a>` tag) then hide it. The tag has some styling to make it look like a button. Essentially, I don't want to show the button unless there's a website or email associated with that address.

Suggestions?

I've tried using jQuery to select the `<a>` tag's class and then hide it, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery is not able to access an element before it's added to the dom, so listen to the `domready`-event of the infoWindow and hide the button then(the  contents of the infoWindow are attached to the DOM at this time, but the infoWindow not opened yet).

But it should be easier when you dont create the button  when you dont need it.

Assuming you use a template, there also is an simple solution:

```
.googft-info-window a[href='']{display:none;}
```

...what will hide all links inside the infowindow with an empty href-attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting an element and hiding it should work for you.  You can make sure that you are selecting it by logging it after the selection.

```
var buttonCnt = $('input.class').length;
console.log(buttoCnt);
```

if the log shows the number of buttons that you expect, then hiding them should be working.  If not, then make sure your selector is being called after the table is populated.